# Accessing Jenkins-home-directory path in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I want to run a script as Jenkins job. The first step of the script is to access Jenkins home-directory path? Is it possible to access this in a script? 
Also if I am not running this script from Jenkins but some remote server how can I access the path

Comment: Have you tried it? If so what were the results? Where did you get stuck? Please expand the question.

Comment: I got it working. In Jenkins, I wrote a shell script to be executed as job. There you have a provision to use many environment variables provided by Jenkins. JENKINS_HOME is one such variable which gives the path of Jenkins home directory@

Comment: Great, now make an answer of what you have learned!

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as other users:

```
cd ~jenkins
```

For imformation, most of the times (by default) `/var/lib/jenkins`